# How to call super in fallback payable function?

Tags: solidity, contract-design, payable

My contract is derived from another contract. And I wish to call the fallback payable function in the super class. May I know how can I do that?

For example:

```
function () public payable
{
    // Do something...

    super();   // Doesn't compile
}
```